# mingw64 - the file has been downloaded incorrectly

Tags: windows-10, mingw-w64

I try to install MinGW-w64, but during install i got

> the file has been downloaded incorrectly

I have 64 bit win10 and my option of installation:

[image]

I use that link [sourceforge.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=directory) and some commentators have same problem.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Revision = 0 seems works

Comment: I had the same problem. For me it worked after redownloading the setup.

Comment: This is a recurring problem. Now it's 2022 and the sourceforge binaries have been broken for many months.

Answer (score 1):

Newer MinGW-w64 releases are now available at https://winlibs.com/ as standalone packages that don't need an installer. Just extract to a folder and start using. This also allows having multiple versions on your side by side (e.g. 32-bit and 64-bit).

Comment: Thank you for this site! As of Februari-somewhere 2022, the official MinGW w64 builds available from Sourceforge have broken binaries. I just downloaded it using winlibs.com instead and it works fine.

Comment: Same approach, without the installer (just unpack yourself) this video helped me [mingw file downloaded incorrectly](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/webdev/mingw-file-downloaded-incorrectly)

Answer (score 0):

This [MinGW article](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/webdev/mingw-file-downloaded-incorrectly) addresses the issue. It's actually pretty simple to fix. The problem is with the Windows installer. What you need to do is download the MinGW zip archive directly (not the installer) and extract the files to something like C:\mingw and then add it to PATH in Environment Variables. Here's direct link to the [SourceForge files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error too. Glad I searched for long until I found this solution.

You should install MinGW64 with this link and use the latest release. https://winlibs.com/#download-release

After you've downloaded it, you should unzip mingw64 file to a location

And then you have to set up the path.
Open your Settings then search for "Edit environment variables for your account", choose the path variable (user) and press edit. Select new and add the bin folder for your mingw64 (location\mingw64\bin, remember to add the \bin at the end).
Press OK and open your cmd. See if you got it by typing: gcc --version