# MinGW x86_64 downloading problem (file incorrectly downloaded )

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I am trying to install MinGW x86_64 from this website:
http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds
But i get a notice by installation said that the file has been downloaded incorrectly!

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript, C++, or CLIon?

Comment: I recommend you to follow this tutorial like I did some days ago: https://youtu.be/0HD0pqVtsmw

Comment: thanks a lot . it woked :)

Comment: The MinGW-w64 standalone build from Https://winlins.com doesn't need installation. Just unzip.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mingw64 - the file has been downloaded incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109422/mingw64-the-file-has-been-downloaded-incorrectly)

Answer (score 0):

This YouTube video [mingw file downloaded incorrectly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcy981HhGw0) has the solution. The basic approach is to download the ZIP archive manually (don't use the Win installer package, and simply unzip contents to C:\mingw, just make sure to add it to PATH in Environment Variables to run system-wide.)